# Direct3d9 load texture fail

Tags: memory, load, directx, textures, direct3d9

I am working on a sort of big project. And I have been facing a fatal problem at the end of the day of the project. I guess it might be from memory leak, anyways please listen to my voice.

The first time I launch the program, it works fine. and I play it for about an hour, then when it moves to next scene (this means destroy all things from the memory and load new things on the memory).

I got a error log saying

```
HeapPool:Init() : can't allocate 33554448 bytes"

Can't Create 2048x2048 texture..
```

something like that.

After the message, textures are gone. I mean the world (in the game) is black. No textures.
Is this problem related to video memory card? physical memory? or virtual memory? I am not an expert about it.

Anyone can give me an hint? Please, I need anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are out of memory, most modern graphics cards can support a 2048 x 2048 texture, anyway, you can check it in DirectX Caps Viewer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I checked it. Mine is 16,384 for MaxTextureWidth and Height. and I am pretty sure there would be memory leak. Anyways, thanks.